# modify php built-in server to route resource requests to my app

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an app locally with Laravel + PHP 5.6.8's built-in server for testing purposes.  On my main server, it's running a vanilla apache+php5.6.8 and I do not have this issue.

When I try to create a route to /api/account/1.json (in laravel Route::get(/api/account/{id}.{format}) and test it locally, it says "resource not found".  It's obviously trying to find the 1.json file rather than parsing it and passing the $id / $format variables.

How do I go about modifying the php.ini to disallow json resources so they get routed to my app?

Comment: I'm affraid that you'll need a real web server (nginx, lighttpd or apache) to do what you want.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping that wouldn't be the case but after pouring through the documentation I think that's what I'm concluding too.

Comment: I know that is kind later but more people can use this as reference... at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) there is sufficient information about how to solve this problem and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#115907) guy has an answer to you. I hope to help someone.